# How to set System EnvVar when UAC is active (Windows Script Host)

Tags: windows, vbscript, environment-variables, uac, wsh

I have to create a script which updates a system environment variable (based on a command line parameter) before launching a program.

In Windows 7, updating the system environment variable is denied. I would like to perform a privilege elevation for just the setting of the env. var. But run the program as a normal user.

How to do it?

Note:
I've tried the following solution:

Using 2 scripts:

- 1 master which get all information from command line, which call the slave script to change the system env. var., and which finally launch the program
- 1 slave script that update the system env. var.
- the master script tries to call the slave script using privilege elevation, but that does not work

I've try 2 solutions for the privilage elevation:

1. Using the "runas /User:Administrator ..." command but it ask for the Administrator password: Fail
2. Using the "ShellExecute ...., "runas"" command but it tells me that my script is not an application: Fail

Comment: Try using runas on cmd.exe or wscript.exe instead of directly on the script.

Comment: @Harry I had tried runas but I have the following caveat: we don't know the Administrator password of our machine. But each of us as administrative rights (to some extent) So I can modify the sys env var from the Windows configuration GUI (after being prompt the UAC). But I cannot use the runas command with my own user, I get a permission denied. And I cannot run it as Administrator as I don't know the password... I really need a simple privilege elevation, just like when I want to perform an administrative task where I simply have to confirm the change. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: I thought the runas verb did the same thing as "run as administrator", i.e., if you're already an administrator it just prompts for approval?

Comment: That's also what I had hoped for :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that is working at least on Windows 7 (don't know if it will work on the few Windows XP hat we still have around).

I did the following from the main script:

```
currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-(len(WScript.ScriptName)))

Set UAC = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", currentDirectory + "my-script.vbs /Param1:Value1 ...", "", "runas", 0
```

And the my-script is doing the sys var env update.

Note: My fist experience with ShellExecute failed because I was trying to execute the script. Instead of "wscript.exe" I had "my-script.vbs" for the executable name.

Comment: Then I launched my executable at the end of my script calling explorer.exe and giving the executable as parameters, so it gets the updated sys env var value!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, disable UAC, it's just a pain in the ***
But if you can't (like me 8<), you can use

```
psexec.exe -d -u userid -p password CMD /c program_with_path
```

You (or the user where the sript runs) will have to confirm the prompt though.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I could deactivate it on my computer, but not on all the computers where the script will run. Furthermore, the userid and password would be user specific which is also something I would like to avoid. Finally, I would really like to avoid having password written in clear in scripts.

Comment: I think it would be a security flaw to not need a user/password, such script could be used as a virus. Why do you need a system var, you have different kind of environment vars, a userenvironment var should be possible to set

Comment: We are using IBM Rational DOORS. There are several colleagues who need 2 (or more) DOORS configuration (different DOORS client version and different DOORS License Server configuration). Sadly, the license configuration is stored in a system environment variable. My goal is to create a generic script which with some parameters can set the right system env. var. for the license server and launch the requested DOORS client version. That's the reward for buying expensive closed-source software :(

Comment: I just would like to have the UAC request, much more like I have when I run an installation program, at some points it is requesting some higher privilege and a popup is displayed with just a Yes/No button dialog. No need for password. In addition I'm trying to limit the privilige elevation just to the setting of the env. var.

Comment: I've tried anyway your command but I ran into the same problem as with runas. Although my account as administrative rights, I don't get the privilege elevation required to set the sys env var (permission which I have). And I don't know the Administrator password. So I cannot use this solution either :( but anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: I meant no disrespect. I simply wanted to explain why I downvoted the answer. While UAC can be annoying, I firmly believe that its benefits outweigh those annoyances. I also believe that administrators and developers are very quick to disable new features without taking the time to learn about them, and comments like the one in your answer add to this mentality.

Comment: Peter, I'm sorry, I just read that downvotes cause you to lose reputation. Had I realized this I would have stuck with a comment.

Comment: @bshacklett, i couldn't be more of the others side about UAC i'm afraid. No offence taken. But stackoverflow is a bad place to discuss about that. Yeah it costs you 10 points to downvote while the downvoted loses only 2. I think you can recuperate your points by clicking once on the upvote and thus annulating the downvote.